# How to place a div on right side of cascading tables - CSS

Tags: css, html-table, css-float

I have 3 tables, cascading one after the other. I have a div, that I want to place on right side of these tables. The height of div may vary according to text inside. Currently the div is displayed below tables, like the image below;

[image: current]

```
<table class="class1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell1</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell3</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="class2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell5</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell7</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="class3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell9</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell11</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="mydiv">mydiv</div>
```

But I want to place the div next to tables, so that it can extend downwards.

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZHVuf/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a container around you table like this :

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
<!-- Your table -->
</div>
```

And make him `float left`, like your div `#myDiv`

**Css**

```
#container {
    float:left;
}
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/ZHVuf/5/).

On this second updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/ZHVuf/8/), I added a wrapper with a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) !

*insertusernamehere* commented that you could use overflow:hidden instead of the clearfix, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/ZHVuf/9/) for a new working way to do this with less code.

Comment: +1 I like the first example better, because you need less markup and the following block level element could simply have `clear:both;` to place it below the other elements. You could also simplify the second example by removing the *clearfix* and simply use this single line on the `wrapper` instead: `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Hmm, I do not understand your comment, I never used overflow hidden ^^. Clear both may not be sufficient in some cases so I rather like this nice clearfix.

Comment: Let me re-phrase it: In you second demo you can remove the class `cf` and simply use `overflow: hidden;` instead. It works like a clearfix but has less code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `float:left;` to all the `table` and add `clear:both;` to second and third table.

now you already has `float:left;` for div just add `position:relative;top:0;` and see.

**OR**

create two divs and add tables in one with left floating and you already have second div.

```
<div class="tableContainerDiv" style="float:left;">
   <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
   <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
   <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</div>
<div class="yourDiv" style="float:left;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```html
<div class="cl">
    <div style="float: left">
        your tables
    </div>
    <div class="mydiv" style="float: left">mydiv</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.cl:after{ content: " ";  display: block; height: 0px; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}
.cl {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \\*/
* html .cl {height: 1%;}
.cl {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Comment: You should add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

move tables inside another div , float to left;

HTML

```
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="class1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell1</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell3</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="class2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell5</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell7</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="class3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell9</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell11</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">mydiv</div>
```

CSS

```
.class1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
.class2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.class3{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: gray;
}
.mydiv{
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    float: left
}
.table-wrap{float:left;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
   <tr><td>
<table class="class1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell1</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell3</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell4</td>
  </tr>
</table>enter code here
<table class="class2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell5</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell7</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="class3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell9</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="cell1">Cell11</td>
    <td class="cell2">Cell12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
       </td>
       <td>
<div class="mydiv">mydiv</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tabular data table inside a table used for layout purposes?  For shame.